# php / wordpress / woocommerce change color of table cell in order details based on value for a woocommerce order

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to find a way to change the background color of a table cell in the order details within woocommerce.  I can't use css as it just comes through in standard table format without any ID's or classes assigned to it.

So I  assume i'll need some php to add to my functions.php to look for any table with the data "gloss" or "matte" and then style the cell that contains those values.

(problem is orders are coming through and people are missing important details when fulfilling orders, I want to make a few things jump out at them based on value)

Any help would be appreciated. I don't know php outside of copy and pasting it.

Some additional information, I'm using PPOM for Woocommerce plugin to get additional fields on products. I'm attaching a screenshot of what it looks like in the order detail. The highlighted line is what I'm looking to be able to show in different colors.THere are only 2 choices, Gloss or Matte. I'd like to be able to highlight each value a different color.

From the product page, this is the html:

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce order admin table has a filter to let you alter the classes on each row.

You can paste this code into your theme's functions.php

```
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_html_order_preview_item_class', 'custom_wc_order_admin_table_row_classes', 10, 2);
function custom_wc_order_admin_table_row_classes($classes, $item, $order)
{
    $product_object = is_callable([$item, 'get_product']) ? $item->get_product() : null;
    if ($product_object) {
        $classes .= 'myspecialclass';
    }
    $classes .= 'mycustomclass1 mycstomclass2';
    return $classes;
}
```

You can customize it to fit your need and then you can add some CSS to make it look as you want.

Not knowing your precise needs doesn't allow me to help you further.
You can edit your question to add some more details if you want

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with using filters to customize it to fit my need, but I'm going to update my question with some more details and hopefully that will help. If there's something specific I can give you that will help customize the filter for me, that would be amazing. Thank you for your time!